# How can i parse specific string using IndexOf?

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
string responser = contents.Substring(f + firstTag.Length, g - f - firstTag.Length);
string dateTag = "בתאריך";
string wroteResponser = ":כתב";
int i = responser.IndexOf(dateTag);
int p = responser.IndexOf(wroteResponser );
string test = responser.Substring(i + dateTag.Length, p + wroteResponser.Length - i - dateTag.Length);
```

In responser i have: כתב: רוטרית   בתאריך: 26.06.14  שעה: 22:58
I want to remove from it this part: כתב: רוטרית

So in the end i will end with this only: בתאריך: 26.06.14  שעה: 22:58
The way im doing it p is -1 all the time and also test i think is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason p = -1 is because wroteResponser should be "כתב:" and not ":כתב"
however, your whole premise is wrong.

you are looking to remove parts.

```
            string responser = "כתב: רוטרית בתאריך: 26.06.14 שעה: 22:58 ";
            string dateTag = "בתאריך";
            string wroteResponser = "כתב:";
            int i = responser.IndexOf(dateTag);
            int p = responser.IndexOf(wroteResponser);


            string test = responser.Remove(p, i);
```

another solution would be with regular expressions

```
        var match = Regex.Match(responser,"כתב: .+בתאריך:(.+) ",RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var u = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

לילה לבן שמח ;)

Comment: תודה מיקי בדיוק חזרנו עכשיו מהלילה הלבן בתל אביב :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use String.Replace("stringyouwantremoved", ""); This will return the original string minus the string you want removed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this responser is in a loop in this example it contain כתב: רוטרית בתאריך: 26.06.14 שעה: 22:58 but in the next itertion it can contain for example: כתב: משה בתאריך: 26.06.14 שעה: 22:58

Comment: What is changing all the time is the name: רוטרית then משה so i need to find how to remove each time: :כותב + the name

Answer (score 0):

Int start = 0;

Int end =[ some number] ;

String test = response. Remove(start,  end) ;

Something like that should work unless I am just not understanding the question.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this responser is in a loop in this example it contain כתב: רוטרית בתאריך: 26.06.14 שעה: 22:58 but in the next itertion it can contain for example: כתב: משה בתאריך: 26.06.14 שעה: 22:58

Comment: What is changing all the time is the name: רוטרית then משה so i need to find how to remove each time: :כותב + the name

Comment: Then do the same thing but use indexOf()

Comment: LOOP{Int start = response. indexOf([what you are looking for]) ; Int end =response. indexOf() ; String test = response. Remove(start, end) ;} END LOOP